# Aggregate function before IObservable sequence is completed

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there a way to use Aggregate function (Max, Count, ....) with Buffer before a sequence is completed.
When Completed this will produce results, but with continues stream it does not give
any results?

I was expecting there is some way to make this work with buffer?

```
IObservable<long> source;
IObservable<IGroupedObservable<long, long>> group  = source
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .GroupBy(i => i % 3);

IObservable<long> sub = group.SelectMany(grp => grp.Max());

sub.Subscribe(l =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("working");
});
```

Comment: What kind of result would you expect from Count until the actual input is completed?

Comment: How many elements was per buffer batch, or what was max element per group for current batch. What I want to achieve is after grouping get element with max Time per group .SelectMany(g => g.Aggregate((minQuote, fxQuote) => minQuote.Time < fxQuote.Time ? fxQuote : minQuote).Select(quote => quote));

Comment: You need to write your own GroupBy for that as GroupBy has no way of knowing when a particular group is finished.

Comment: GroupBy works fine, SelectMany works fine as long as I don't use aggregate function (Max) inside. This is working 
group.SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(g => new { newProp = g}));

Comment: GroupBy returns an observable for each group that doesn't know the contents of each group until the entire input sequence has been consumed. As such, GroupBy doesn't work fine as how the groups work is integral to how GroupBy was implemented. If you know that once you've gotten items that belong in a different group, the previous group is completed, you can build a GroupBy that uses that knowledge to complete each group.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I do get back IGroupedObservable when subscribe and I do need to wait until Source is completed to get results back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the "statistical" operators in Rx (Min/Max/Sum/Count/Average) are using a mechanism that propagate the calculate value just when the subscription is completed, and that is the big difference between `Scan` and `Aggregate`, basically if you want to be notified when a new value is pushed in your subscription it is necessary to use `Scan`.

In your case if you want to keep the same logic, you should combine with `GroupByUntil` or `Window` operators, the conditions to use both can create and complete the group subscription regularly, and that will be used to push the next value.

You can get more info here:  http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#BuildYourOwn

By the way I wrote a text related to what you want. Check in: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/853256/Real-time-statistics-with-Rx-Statistical-Demo-App

Answer (score 5):

Use `Scan` instead of `Aggregate`.  Scan works just like Aggregate except that it sends out intermediate values as the stream advances.  It is good for "running totals", which appears to be what you are asking for.